# Android app doesn't show up in Google Play

Tags: google-play

I just published my first app days ago but I'm having troubles finding it with the search option. The app has its download page, it's compatible with my device but even if I search the exact name it doesn't show up in the search results. So is it just a matter of time, or I'm missing something?

Comment: I have same issue. Could you figure it out?